# Write data present in list to a column in excel sheet using xlxs writer module

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

I have two lists defined as:

```
Column1=[1,2,3,4]
Column2=[5,6,7,8]
```

I want to append the `Column1` list to first column of an Excel sheet and the `Column2` list to the second column of the Excel sheet.  Excel sheet would look like:

[image]

**My Code So Far:**

```
from xlxswriter import*
workbook=Workbook('Ecl.xlxs')
Report_Sheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
for row_ind,row_value in enumerate(Column1):
    print row_ind,row_value
    Report_Sheet.write('A',Column1)#i want something similar to this
```

So each list should be appended to each column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Column1':[1,2,3,4],'Column2':[5,6,7,8]})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
```

The `test.xlsx` will be like the one you need.

Update:

```
import pandas as pd
Column1 = [1,2,3,4]
Column2 = [5,6,7,8]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Column1':Column1,'Column2':Column2})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Column1':Column1,'Column2':Column2})

Comment: Can I add list name here instead of [1,2,3,4]??

Comment: @user1681102 yes, you can, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

XlsxWriter has [`write_row()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-row) and [`write_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-column) methods to write lists of data in a single call. So you could write your column data like this:

```
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

Column1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Column2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

workbook = Workbook('Ecl.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write the column headers if required.
Report_Sheet.write(0, 0, 'Column1')
Report_Sheet.write(0, 1, 'Column2')

# Write the column data.
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 0, Column1)
Report_Sheet.write_column(1, 1, Column2)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Note: there is a typo in the file extension in your sample code. It is important in Excel to have the correct extension.

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip()` and `enumerate()` can get the values you need to iterate over your data like:

**Code:**

```
Column1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Column2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

from xlsxwriter import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('Ecl.xlsx')
Report_Sheet=workbook.add_worksheet()
Report_Sheet.write(0, 0, 'Column1')
Report_Sheet.write(0, 1, 'Column2')

for row_ind, row_value in enumerate(zip(Column1, Column2)):
    print row_ind, row_value
    for col_ind, col_value in enumerate(row_value):
        Report_Sheet.write(row_ind + 1, col_ind, col_value)
```

Comment: Do I have to close the excel sheet to see the changes in the excel sheet?

Comment: Always a good idea to close when done.  Although in my testing it worked fine to just end the program.

Comment: I don't see anything being appended to the excel sheet,